# Multithreading with Windows API in C

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I have written the code as follow and supposedly it should print out numbers from 0 to 10 in a random order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define THREAD_COUNT 10

DWORD WINAPI t_work(LPVOID param) {
    printf("%d\n", *((int *) param));
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    DWORD *thread_id = malloc(THREAD_COUNT * sizeof(DWORD));
    HANDLE *threads = malloc(THREAD_COUNT * sizeof(HANDLE));
    int *data = malloc(THREAD_COUNT * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        *(data + i) = i;
        //printf("Debugging value: %d\n", i);
        *(threads + i) = CreateThread(
            NULL,               // default security attributes
            0,                  // use default stack size
            t_work,             // thread function name
            (data + i),         // argument to thread function
            0,                  // use default creation flags
            (thread_id + i));   // returns the thread identifier
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREAD_COUNT, threads, TRUE, INFINITE);
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < THREAD_COUNT; k++) {
        CloseHandle(*(threads + k));
    }

    // free memory
    free(thread_id);
    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, for whatever reason, the printout is always incorrect. There are always some random numbers missing and some duplicated. Following are a few run results of the program:

**Run #1**

```
PS C:\Users\tdw\Work\C Test Project> .\hw.exe
0
8
9
9
9
1
3
5
4
2
```

**Run #2**

```
PS C:\Users\tdw\Work\C Test Project> .\hw.exe
0
6
6
8
8
9
9
4
3
3
```

**Edit 1:**

I'm using Visual Studio Code Version 1.50.1

Here's the detail of compiler:

```
PS C:\Users\tdw\Work\C Test Project> gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86_64/src/gcc-10.2.0/configure - 
-srcdir=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86_64/src/gcc-10.2.0 --prefix=/usr -- 
exec- 
prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc -- 
docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc 
--htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64- 
pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without- 
libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable- 
shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific- 
runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with- 
tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable- 
graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable- 
libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada -- 
disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog- 
include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl- 
prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx- 
abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: I don't think your pointer arithmetic is correct.  Wouldn't you prefer to use an array instead?

Comment: Should be `*(data + i * sizeof(HANDLE))`

Comment: Also, your `t_work` function should return something! Add `return 0;` as its last line.

Comment: Need to use `_beginthread()`, not `CreateThread()`, btw.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sorry. I do not follow. Are you referring to the line for memory allocation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Huh? I agree that array indexing would be better, but pointer arithmetic works OK, implicitly factoring-in the size of the pointee.

Comment: @AdrianMole You're correct. It does not change the outcome though.

Comment: I don't like the style of the code, notably about indexing, nor the missing return values. But I read several times the function and can't imagine an explanation, it should work for me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - you are wrong, `*(data + i ) = i;` correct, of course possible use `data[i] = i;` too

Comment: Unless HANDLE is only a single byte in size, I don't see how I am incorrect.  An array would remove all doubt in any case.  So would adding `sizeof(HANDLE)` to the calculation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `data` is an `int*` variable, so `(data + 1)` will add `sizeof(int)` to `data`.

Comment: Ah, right.  I forgot, C already takes the type size into account.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -`data` is pointer to `int` and unrelated to `HANDLE`. you 100% wrong

Comment: @Will I can't reproduce your error. Your code (with or without the `return 0`) runs as expected with VS-2019, using either clang-cl or MSVC.

Comment: I still think this would be a whole lot simpler to reason about by using ordinary arrays.

Comment: On which version of MSVC does the code produce the wrong result? In Debug or Release mode (it probably matters when dealing with multitasking)?

Comment: i be say that code basically ok, for debug - print also thread id. so `printf("++%x> %u\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), *((int *) param));` in `t_work` and `printf("--%x> %u\n", thread_id[i], data[i]);` after `CloseHandle(threads[--i]);`

Comment: @prapin - version of MSVC here unrelated

Comment: @AdrianMole I've updated the question with environment information.

Comment: @Will - this information nothing give. if want really more info - print thread id in working threads with number. and after thread exit - in loop where you close handles - again print thread id with number. and compare/post results

Comment: @RbMm As you can see in the original code, I did have some debugging statements in there. It didn't help resolve the issue, though.

Comment: @Will - print `printf("++%x> %u\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), *((int *) param));` and in close loop `printf("--%x> %u\n", thread_id[i], data[i]);`

Comment: I tried a lot of times this code on MSVC 2019, both in Debug and Release, both in 32-bit and 64-bit. I see no problem at all. Puzzling.

Comment: ... but with GCC on Cygwin, version 9.3.0, I indeed reproduce the error!

Comment: I think the problem is on the I/O, while calling `printf`. I see sometimes weird characters that should not be present.

Comment: Yes! I was right, the problem lies in `printf`. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in thread function `t_work`, which is calling `printf`.
Depending on your platform, `printf` is not necessarily re-entrant.
On Visual Studio environment, `printf` is probably protected with some mutex, and everything works.
But with GCC and its *libc*, races can happen in that I/O function.

Solution: use a mutex to protect `printf`.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define THREAD_COUNT 10
static CRITICAL_SECTION mutex;

DWORD WINAPI t_work(LPVOID param) {
    EnterCriticalSection(&mutex);
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)param));
    LeaveCriticalSection(&mutex);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&mutex);
    DWORD* thread_id = malloc(THREAD_COUNT * sizeof(DWORD));
    HANDLE* threads = malloc(THREAD_COUNT * sizeof(HANDLE));
...
```

Comment: This answer is spot on!